# Cells with data shared

Tags: mysql

If i have that table (MYSQL) like this

```
name          |         email |        cites |
Alberto       |     inf@gmail |           12 |
Berta         |    bert@gmail |            3 |
Carlos        |  carl@hotmail |           12 |
```

Is posible make a link between carlos.cites and Alberto.cites inside the same table So when cell Alberto.cites is updated cell Carlos.cites is updated. Like a link permanent. Both allways show the same value?

Comment: No, there's no such thing in relational databases. If `cites` is the same entity for both records, then it should be a single entity in a different table, and in your table you would have a foreign key reference to that.

Comment: I think you could implement your own functionality for this by having another column which defines the relationship between the two rows (i.e. each has the ID of the other row stored in another column), and then use triggers to UPDATE the paired row when one of them is updated. Might be trickier if you need more than 2 rows to be grouped together though.